# Extending BaseClass method (Polymorphism)

Tags: ruby, oop, polymorphism

I played around with inheritances and tried to extend a method from the base class from the subclass. Polymorphism. Basically, I tried to extend the base method (status) with an additional option.

However, for some reason it doesn't work as expected. I thought B.new.status(1) would return 2 instead of nil.

If I place super after "y if opt == 2" then the results are vice verse.

Why is that and how can I solve this problem?

Many thanks in advance!

```
    class A
      attr_reader :x

      def initialize
        @x = 2
      end

      def status(opt)
        x if opt == 1
      end
    end

    class B < A
      attr_reader :y

      def initialize
        super
        @y = 10
      end

      def status(opt)
        super
        y if opt == 2
      end
    end

    B.new.status(1)
    => nil
    B.new.status(2)
    => 2
```

Comment: From a design point of view, it would be better to enforce for sub-classes that the base class function is called first. This can be easily achieved with the template-method pattern.

Comment: Good point. You mean, I should wipe the code from the status method in class A and place it into the status method of class B. Thus, status method of class B would have: "x if opt == 1" and "y if opt == 2". Moreover, I wouldn't need to call super in status method anymore, right?

Comment: No, I mean that A.status does the work that is common for all types, and then calls an (abstract) method which sub-classes override. This way, every sub-class just implements the sub-class specific functionality, and the base-class implements the protocol once and for all. It's the template method design pattern: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because the return value from `A`'s `status` is not used in `B`'s `status`. Yes, in `A`'s status, `'x'` will be returned, but that isn't used in `B`'s `status`.

The result of the last statement in a method is automagically returned, but `super` isn't the last statement in `B`'s `status`.

Answer (score 0):

If the codition of an if statement is not satisfied, it returns nil. So you should do something like this:

```
if opt == 2
  y
else
  super
end
```

Comment: Or `opt == 2 ? y : super`